# How to run VSCode as root on WSL 2 without changing the default user?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo

I want to use VSCode with `WSL` extension (installed natively in Windows 10) as the editor for `sudoedit` and `visudo` commands of WSL 2 Debian 12 distro (which runs on the same phisical machine).

To accomplish this, I have done:

- Added the following to `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  # Set Visual Studio Code as the default editor for sudoedit and visudo.
  # Support from sudoers is required for this change to take effect.
  export SUDO_EDITOR='code --new-window --wait'
  ```
- Created `/etc/sudoers.d/sudoers` file with the following content (not all text here is directly related to the task, but I am posting the whole file for clarity):

  ```
  # Relax default restrictions established by the top-level sudoers file
  Defaults !env_reset
  Defaults !authenticate
  Defaults !secure_path
  Defaults !sudoedit_checkdir

  # Editor configuration
  Defaults env_editor

  # Grant the default user (named admin) all possible sudo rights
  admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
  ```
- Restarted WSL.

After that, when I type `sudoedit /etc/sudoers` into WSL terminal, a VSCode window with the standard top-level `sudo` config opens. I can make changes, save and close the file, and it will be updated correctly. However, when using `sudo visudo` instead, the editor displays an error after loading:

```
The editor could not be opened due to an unexpected error: Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://wsl+debian/etc/sudoers.tmp' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): An unknown error occurred. Please consult the log for more details.)
```

The logs (both local and server-side) give no additional information except that `/etc/sudoers.tmp` is really unreadable due to insufficient rights.

I performed some sort of investigation and realized that VSCode always runs as `admin` (my default unprivileged user) even when was called with `sudo`.

So, the question: is there any way to make VSCode work as the editor for `visudo`? Or, more generally: how to run it with `root` privileges on demand?

Comment: Oh, please don't do that.  Think about what you're asking.  VSCode is an Electron app.  That means it's just a bunch of Javascript that is running inside an instance of the Chrome browser.  You don't seriously want your browser to have root access.  Just use `vi`.

Comment: Did you find desicion?

Comment: @sergzemsk, nope, simply gave up the idea of a regular default user; now I am working under `root` account only, and my VSCode is always `root`, too ☺ Never have faced any problems with this approach, although it is widely known as an unsafe and bad practice. And the crutial feature for me is that I am now completely free of `sudo` and related stuff, which sometimes were turning my life into bloody hell.